# Select biggest polygon area for each id

Tags: postgresql, postgis

I have a subquery that produces something like

```
   pointid   | polygonid  |    area
-------------+------------+-------------
   699724666 |    3810527 | 2.06199e-07
   699927129 |    3810527 | 2.06199e-07
  1022506588 |    4793274 | 1.7602e-07
  1510712278 |    9888241 | 4.63377e-07
  3633280129 |   14039247 | 1.4738e-07
   767859914 |   14363105 | 1.21193e-05
  1602741932 |   22982686 | 2.78871e-07
  2094064279 |   23106078 | 1.72662e-07
    23399836 |   23399836 | 7.93616e-07   -- this is the biggest area of both records
    23399836 |   23458583 | 3.43948e-08   -- i don't need this
    24203901 |   24203901 | 3.04905e-08
...
   286850518 | 1190017878 | 4.48722e-10
 11049705806 | 1190017879 | 1.22384e-09
   334276998 | 1190578569 | 1.64479e-09
   334276996 | 1190578570 | 1.45084e-09
  1193281123 | 1193281123 | 4.718e-09
   984013344 | 1194854105 | 6.69957e-10
 11152960476 | 1203094927 | 1.23606e-09
(1611 rows)
```

It is sorted by `polygonid, area desc`. The `pointid` 23399836 occurs twice and I only want the one with bigger area.

In other words: I need all records, but out of any group of "duplicates", only the one with the biggest area. There may even be more than 2 "duplicates" per `pointid`.

Comment: Use `select distinct on (pointid) * from <table> order by area desc`

Comment: i knew it had to be pretty simple, but i didn't think of that.

Answer (score 1):

Slight correction but mostly filling [Mike's straight-to-the-point comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77054349/bind-biggest-polygons-in-a-list-of-data#comment135838220_77054349) with typical answer details:

Whenever you're seeing groups with a common feature and wish to keep only one, "top" specific record out of each group, you're thinking [`distinct on`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-DISTINCT): [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/tTkH7R3-)

```sql
select distinct on (pointid)--in parenthesis, you put the group's common feature
       *                    --list what you want to get, as usual
from your_table 
order by pointid,           --the common feature comes first, 
         area desc;         --rest of `order by` decides which one ends up "top"
```

It's possible to get that result by other means, but in your scenario that's the shortest and most effective one. Whenever you want more than the single top record per group, you'll need to consider [window functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-window.html), joining with `WITH` [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html)'s, [lateral subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-table-expressions.html#QUERIES-LATERAL) and [SRF](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-srf.html)'s. If you want just one but find it easier to specify your criteria some other way than "top one in this order", [scalar subqueries](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-SCALAR-SUBQUERIES) with a [`limit`/`offset`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-limit.html).